# Mootools element > Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'addEvent'

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$$('.img-default > a')[0]
```

Delivers me the correct element in the DOM. However, I am not able to add an event.

This code:

```
$$('.img-default > a')[0].addEvent('click', function(){ //GA code  });
```

results in:

`Object #[HTMLDivElement] has no method 'addEvent'`

I followed the docs, which seems pretty straightforward:
http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Event

**EDIT:**
They seem to have changed Mootools with jQuery overtime. This was possible because Mootools wasn’t used extensively and easily replaceable. They, however, apparently never informed us about this.

```
$('.img-default > a').click(function() {  alert('clicked'); });
```

this works but links it to al the elements in the array, dont want that

```
$('.img-default > a')[0]
```

this returns the href wrapping the big image nicely

```
$('.img-default > a')[0].click(function() {  alert('clicked'); });
```

this however, doesnt
 work >> **TypeError: Object [object HTMLAnchorElement] has no method 'click'**

Seen this before with jQuery in unsorted lists. Wasnt able to link an index of the

elements.

Comment: are you sure $$ is owned by mootools? $$ is now exported by chrome and firebug as well as a shortcut to QSA. even so, Element.prototype in these browsers still works, so that leaves IE8 or less. for single element, use `document.getElement('.img-default >a')` or `node.getElement` / `node.getElements` to anchor up the dom tree. which version of mootools also? do you have a domready? has it been loaded? this is rather elementary and should be very easy to setup...

Comment: @Dimitar: $$ was previously shurely owned by Mootools. have to recheck based on your input. It concerns the large call to action image at http://www.voordeelpas.nl

Comment: `$$.toSource()` on your page -> "function () {
    [native code]
}" - fail. also. `MooTools` -> ReferenceError: MooTools is not defined
[Break On This Error]  

MooTools

Comment: lol - see http://voordeelpas.jongegezinnen.nl/static/jgfreestyle/sites/voordeelpas2/_scripts/mootools-1.2.1-core.js - it's mootools file but inside, there is jquery :)

Comment: dafuqq?! have to talk to my technology suplier then... :p

Comment: jQuery has a different api, you need to use the wrapped els - can't call methods directly on the HTMLElement. Re-tagged question as jquery so you can get appropriate help

Answer (score 0):

try to add add dom ready function :

```
window.addEvent('domready',function() {
// you stuff
});
```